# Unable to hear audio from Asterisk server

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

I am running an Asterisk server in Public IP. When I connect SIP softphones to the server, I am able to make call and conversation is possible between the softphones. However, anything that is played on the asterisk server is not heard in the softphone. In asterisk server log, I could see the message like " Playing 'hello-world.gsm' " but I could not hear any message.

Ports open for sending and receiving UDP packets in the server are 5060, 10000 to 20000, 4569, 5036 and 2727

When I setup the server inside the LAN, everything was working perfectly. So I suspect it could be related to some firewall configuration. Please help me.

Note : SIP softphones were running in a machine connected to internet using wifi dongle with Cone NAT

Comment: I am awaiting. Someone please help me

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify it seems like your asterisk box is on a LAN, and there is a NAT device which provides the public IP address. In this case, you should configure asterisk for  network address translation.

In sip.conf set the following parameters to their correct values:

```
directmedia = no
nat = force_rport,comedia
canreinvite = no
insecure = port,invite
localnet = 
externip/externhost =
```

Use the `sip set debug on` command to verify asterisk replaces it's local address with the externip in sip dialogs to your public clients.

Also `rtp set debug on` can be used to show if audio (RTP) packets are reaching the asterisk box.